# Create shortcut that opens with Edge in kiosk mode in Wix

Tags: wix

I need to create a shortcut on the Desktop and start menu using Wix, that opens a certain URL in kiosk mode with Edge. The full target is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk "https://example.com" --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen
```

My installer does not have an exe, just a custom ico for the shortcut. Checking if Edge is installed is another question. I think Edge is always installed in the same location. Can I use the  tag for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `Shortcut` element can be used since the `Target` attribute is formattable. Something like:

```
<Shortcut Target='[ProgramFilesFolder]Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
          Arguments='--kiosk "https://example.com" --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen' />
```